# AlertDialog won't show

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-context

I'm trying to show an alert dialog in my code.
It needs a `Context` when it is building as its parameter.
I want it to pop up in my `LoginActivity`:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    { 
            // Methods inside         
    }
```

But my function which generates the `alertDialog` is in a separate class. So in order to get the appropriate `Context` I tried an extra class which gives me the `ApplicationContext`, which I then use as the required parameter.

Here is my function which generates the `alertDialog`:

```
    public static void alertFailure(String errorTitle, String errorMessage){
            Log.d("Alert Failure", "alerting failure");
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApplication.getAppContext()); // Needs context of loginactivity
            builder.setTitle(errorTitle);
            builder.setMessage(errorMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
    }
```

And here is my class which I use for getting the `ApplicationContext`:

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application{
        private static Context context;

        public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();
            MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
        }

        public static Context getAppContext(){
            return context;
        }
    }
```

When I log my program I can see that my function is running fine, but the `alertDialog` doesn't pop up. How can I pass the `Context` of my `LoginActivity` as the parameter?

Comment: I think you should pass Context to `alertFailure` as parameter.

Comment: In MyApplication, try to assign context this way: `MyApplication.context = this;`

Comment: Just do this AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can overload the method

```
public static void alertFailure(Context context, String errorTitle, String errorMessage) {
 Log.d("Alert Failure", "alerting failure");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); // Needs context of loginactivity
        builder.setTitle(errorTitle);
        builder.setMessage(errorMessage);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
}
```

and call it like `NomeClass.alertFailure(LoginActivity.this, "title", "message");`

and you can keep the version without context:

```
public static void alertFailure(String errorTitle, String errorMessage){
      alertFailure(MyApplication.getContext(), erroTitle, errorMessage);
 }
```

Comment: When I use 'LoginActivity.this' it says the activity is not an enclosing class.

Comment: are you calling it from a static method?

Comment: Yes, my function is defined as static

Comment: then you don't have access to the outer environment

Comment: So if I would make it public and create a object for using my method, it should work fine?

Comment: depends on what you want you to make public. Don't take me wrong, java basics are essentials

Comment: I'm not having much success. Tomorrow I will take a close look. I gotta go

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I got it fixed. I changed my function to non static, made an object and put the context as a parameter for my function. Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this..

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

with this..

```
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an activity context for dialogs. The application context won't do.

You can pass it as a parameter to the method, e.g.

```
public static void alertFailure(Activity context, String errorTitle, String errorMessage){
```

And calling from an activity:

```
AnotherClass.alertFailure(this, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

add another parameter as ActivityContext in the alertFailure(), then call the `alertFailure("Alert Failure", "alerting failure", LoginActivity.this);` from LoginActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a problem with `Context`.

Call `alertFailure` like this:

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        alertFailure("Title", "Message");
    }
});
```